# Woocommerce function for add-to-cart inside "content-product.php"

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change this part inside `yourtheme/woocommerce/content-product.php`:

```
<li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

<a href="<strong><?php the_permalink(); ?></strong>">...
```

Here we got a product image with the permalink for the `/shop` page. Every product image gets the permalink for the specific product ID page.

Here I want to add the direct function for add-to-cart (?). I need an advise for what I can call inside this `a href="..."`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WooCommerce has a query string that'll do just that. First you'll need to remove your HTML (the `<strong>` tags) from inside the anchor tag, that's not valid markup.

Then you'll need to do something like:

`<a href="<?php echo get_site_url() . '/cart/?add-to-cart=' . get_the_id() ?>"> ... </a>`

The ID should be echoed from that function because you're within the loop, and that syntax is all you need in order add an item to the cart, and redirect a user to the cart page once it's been added. You'll need to ensure the AJAX add to cart option in WooCommerce settings is enabled.

Comment: It's best not to hard-code domains like that. You're better off using `get_permalink()`: `<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'Cart' ) ) ) . '?add-to-cart=' . get_the_ID() ?>`. Also important: `the_id()` isn't the right function to use here.

Comment: @rnevius You're right, as for getting the page by title, there's still a chance of the cart page not being "Cart," (i.e. "Bag" for instance), so using that function's no more reliable than using the slug. He can adjust if need be. I've updated the href to use the site URL though, concatenated with the slug and query string, and revised function.

Comment: Thanks a lot to you guys. Nice solution to fix my issue. get_the_id() is fetching the right IDs inside the loop. Cool one. ;)